# Mysql Dynamic Table expanding columns

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am wondering if there is a better way to make some mysql tables than what I have been using in this project. I have a series of numbers which represent a specific time. Such as the number 101 would represent Jan 12, 2012 for example. It doesn't only represent time but that is the very basic of that information. So I created a lexicon table which has all the numbers we use and details such as time and meaning of that number. I have another table that is per customer which whenever they make a purchase I check off that the purchase is eligiable for a specific time. But the table where I check off each purchase and the lexicon table are not linked. I am wondering if there is a better way, maybe a way to have an sql statement take all the data from the Lexicon table and turn that into columns while the rows consist of customer ID and a true/false selector.

```
 table structure

 THIS IS THE CUSTOMER PURCHASED TABLE T/F
 CREATE TABLE `group1` (
`100` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`101` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
`102` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT '0',
... this goes on for 35 times each table
PRIMARY KEY (`CustID`)
 )


 THIS IS THE LEXICON TABLE
 CREATE TABLE `lexicon` (
`Number` INT(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`OtherPurtinantInfo` .... etc

 )
```

So I guess instead of making groups of numbers every season for the customers I would prefer being able to use the updated lexicon table to automatically generate a table. My only concerns are that we have many many numbers so that would make a very large table all combined together but perhaps that could be limited into groups automatically as well so that it is not an overwhelming table.

I am not sure if I am being clear enough so feel free to comment on things that need to be clarified.

Comment: The lack of normalization is making my head hurt.

Comment: I made this program 8 years ago, it was one of my first endeavors into database management it happens to be the most used program of mine. Lol so there are certainly some pitfalls, having multiple tables is a bit more tedious... So while I'm updating it might as well normalize it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a normalized ERD, based on what I understand your business requirements to be:

[image]

The classifieds run on certain dates, and a given advertisement can be run for more than one classifieds date.

The SQL statements to make the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `classified_ads` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `classified_dates` (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `info` TEXT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `classified_ad_dates` (
    `classified_ad_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `classifiend_date_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`classified_ad_id`, `classifiend_date_id`),
    INDEX `fk_classified_ad_dates_classified_ads1` (`classified_ad_id` ASC),
    INDEX `fk_classified_ad_dates_classified_dates1` (`classifiend_date_id` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_classified_ad_dates_classified_ads1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`classified_ad_id`)
        REFERENCES `classified_ads` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_classified_ad_dates_classified_dates1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`classifiend_date_id`)
        REFERENCES `classified_dates` (`id`)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Hey Sonny, does that image happen to be taken from an online tool?

Comment: just to ensure I understood. This is a many to many relationship between the table that holds the Date definitions and the ads... (You sir have a keen eye, I thought I removed all references to what type of program this was -.- albeit it probably helped you identify the problem right away.) If this is the case I know how to proceed now, Thanks :)

Comment: @Mallow - That's exactly what this is. One Ad can be run for many Dates, and each Date can have many Ads.

Comment: In thinking about it a little more I'd probably change the table names a bit, but as long as this gets you going in the right direction, it's good. Something like this: `customers <- ads <- ad_runs -> runs`

Comment: the table names aren't a big deal, I already have two of the tables in place, I just need to make the many to many relationship table and replace my five redundant lookup tables.